# css not working on my firefox extension toolbar

Tags: css, firefox-addon

iam writing a simple firefox toolbar, but i have failed to set a few list style images with css. Please help.
//

**katimbatoolbar.css**

(found in chrome/skin) folder

```
#katimbatoolbarstart
{
    list-style-image :url("chrome://katimbatoolbar/skin/button-1.png");
}
```

**katimbatoolbar.xul** (my user interface file, found in "chrome/content/" folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://katimbatoolbar/skin/tuttoolbar.css" type="text/css"?>

<overlay id="katimbatoolbaroverlay"
         xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
         
    <script type="application/x-javascript"
            src="chrome://katimbatoolbar/content/katimbatoolbar.js" />
            
    <toolbox id="navigator-toolbox">
    
        <toolbar id="katimbatoolbar" toolbarname="katimba suite" accesskey="k"
                 class="chromeclass-toolbar" context="toolbar-context-menu" 
                 hidden="false" persist="hidden">
                <toolbarbutton id="katimbatoolbarstart" tooltiptext="start surfing using katimba ++"
                    label="Start" oncommand="katimbaClass.installLocalHost()"/>                     

        </toolbar>
    </toolbox>
</overlay>
```

Here is my **chrome.manifest** file

```
content katimbatoolbar chrome/content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://katimbatoolbar/content/katimbatoolbar.xul
skin katimbatoolbar classic/1.0 chrome/skin/
```

The toolbar works fine, but really looks ugly since the css is not working. Any help appreciated in advance.
By the way, Here is my folder structure

```
mytoolbar/
          install.rdf
          chrome.manifest
          chrome/
                content/
                    katimbatoolbar.xul
                    katimbatoolbar.js
                skin/
                    katimbatoolbar.css
                    button-1.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XUL file you reference chrome://katimbatoolbar/skin/tuttoolbar.css while the file in your folder structure is called katimbatoolbar.css. Plus, you define

```
content katimbatoolbar chrome/content/
```

but the folder structure starts with mytoolbar.